# Noobs approach to automate x264 cmd

Tags: video-encoding, x264

so here is my script to loop through specific video extensions » add a manual profile » generate necessary *.bat & finally a final 'loader' batch file to execute previous *.bat files sequentially & necessary logging (this gives quiet a deal of freedom if you so want)

```
::==
:: gets lines into vars c1 v2 v...
@echo off
:: user input required
cd /d "d:\Trainers\out\"
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
dir /B /O:N | findstr ".wmv$ " >filename.txt
echo. >log.txt
:: user input required
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('type filename.txt ^|findstr ".wmv$"') do (
set /a n+=1
echo. >file!n!.bat
set in=%in%%%a
:: user input required
set out=!in:.wmv=.mp4!
:: user input required
set v=x264 --crf 23  --level 3.1 --tune film -o "d:\Trainers\out\!in!" "d:\Trainers\out\!out!"
echo. !v!>file!n!.bat
)
dir /B /O:N | findstr ".bat$ " >x264_home.txt
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (x264_home.txt) do (
set /a n+=1
:: mtee is an external library Google it
set "z=call %%a | mtee /d/c/t/+ log.txt"
echo. !z! >> x264_home.bat
)
echo. @echo off > newFile.bat
type x264_home.bat >> newFile.bat
type newFile.bat > x264_home.bat
del newFile.bat,x264_home.txt,filename.txt
echo. pause >> x264_home.bat
echo. @echo All Operation done... >> x264_home.bat
:: user input required
move "d:\Trainers\out\*.bat" "d:\Program Files\x264_auto\test\"
:: user input required
move "d:\Trainers\out\log.txt" "d:\Program Files\x264_auto\test\"
::==
```

Now the above code which is fairly easy to understand (bcz its written by a noob) run perfectly & create necessary files. For instance one of the file1.bat looks like this:

```
x264 --crf 23  --level 3.1 --tune film --preset veryslow --deblock -2:-1 --zones 24233,25324,q=20 --acodec aac --abitrate 80 -o "d:\Trainers\out\1.wmv" "d:\Trainers\out\1.mp4"
```

...& the loader .bat file looks like

```
 @echo off 
 call file1.bat | mtee /d/c/t/+ log.txt 
 call file2.bat | mtee /d/c/t/+ log.txt
 call file3.bat | mtee /d/c/t/+ log.txt
 @echo All Operation done...
```

You see this is a quiet flexible approach in that you can use special filestr » set another loop » set another profile. Furthermore every batch file can be latter edited especiialy when you heavily use `--zone` x264 feature
I am successful because there is no error in any output ...but its the x264.exe (provider/compiler x264GUI) throws error which it otherwise don't?

```
d:\Program Files\x264_auto\test>x264 --crf 23  --level 3.1 --tune film --preset
veryslow --deblock -2:-1 --zones 24233,25324,q=20 --acodec aac --abitrate 80 -o
"d:\Trainers\out\1.wmv" "d:\Trainers\out\1.mp4"
ffms [error]: could not create index
lavf [error]: could not open input file
raw [error]: raw input requires a resolution.
x264 [error]: could not open input file `d:\Trainers\out\1.mp4' via any method!
```

its the x264 thats the culprit perhaps a senior guide is required here

Answer (score -1):

Is your x264 compiled with mp4 input support? (I believe that needs lavc/lavformat, just download precompiled x264 from x264.nl which has all extras)

Do you get the same error if you run the same command directly? (not through bat files)

If yes, does it only happen when you use zones? (if it does, then post an example of your command line as x264 bug to x264-devel mailing list)

If no, are you sure you are running the exact same x264? (perhaps there are several in different places on your system)

I recommend doing what you're doing either (a) in python with subprocess.call(...) or (b) in cygwin/bash/shell script, or .  bat files are pretty much the wrong answer to any problem :)  The nice thing about either of those two is that they have simple, regular escaping rules for program arguments.